# Расчет количества простых чисел в интервале

Tags: java, алгоритм, простые-числа

Задание - посчитать количество простых чисел от 2 до х, используя вложенный цикл for + for. Помогите доработать код, тест-методы со значениями finish = 2 и finish = 11 - выполняются, а со значением 5 - нет

```
public class PrimeNumber {

 public int calc(int finish) {
    int count = 0;
    boolean isPrime;
    if (!(finish == 2)) {
        for (count = 2; count <= finish; count++) {
            isPrime = true;

            for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(count); j++) {
                if ((count % j) == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                }
                else  {
                    return count;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
    return count;
}
}
```

Comment: Где у Вас считается "количество"? Как можно в такой задаче что-то возвращать изнутри двойного цикла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function calc(finish) {
  var result = 0;

  for (var count = 2; count <= finish; count++) {
    var isPrime = true;
    for (var j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(count); j++) {
      if (count % j == 0) {
        isPrime = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (isPrime)
      result++;
  }

  return result;
}
console.log(calc(2));
console.log(calc(5));
console.log(calc(100));
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо ребята, все работает!

Comment: @PaulV Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы несколько ускорил код @Igor - ну, не вижу смысла проверять четные числа на делимость, и проверять делимость на четные числа. А раз минимальное число диапазона - 2, то это 2 можно вынести отдельно...

```js
    function calc(finish) {
      var result = 1;
    
      for (var count = 3; count <= finish; count+=2) {
        var isPrime = true;
        for (var j = 3; j*j <= count; j+=2) {
          if (count % j == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (isPrime)
          result++;
      }
      return result;
    }
    console.log(calc(2));
    console.log(calc(5));
    console.log(calc(100));
```

А, да, на Java - вроде бы так:

```
public class PrimeNumber {

    public int calc(int finish)
    {
        int result = 1;
        for(int count = 3; count <= finish; count += 2)
        {
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for(int j = 3; j*j <= count; j+=2)
            {
                if (count % j == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPrime) ++result;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```